# C# create iterable list of settings with different data types

Tags: c#, generics, subclass, iterable

I am pulling my hair out on this one. It seems so simple but it's not.  I just want to create a simple list of settings.  Each setting has a "name", "value" and "default".  Each setting's "value"/"default" can be any simple type (bool, int, float, string, etc).

It seems the list needs to be iterable so I can implement read/write functions to save the settings and load them later, or search for a setting by name to determine if it exists, return its value, etc.

Here is what I tried (among lots of other things):

```
abstract class BaseSetting
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Setting<T> : BaseSetting
{
   public Setting(string name, T value, T def) { Name = name; Value = value; DefaultValue = def; }
   public T Value { get; set; }
   public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
}


// Create iterable list of settings:
List<BaseSetting> Settings = new List<BaseSetting>(); // Have to use the Base class so the list will accept subclasses with various types.

// Add subclasses of various types to the list:
Settings.Add(new Setting<int>("IntSetting", 123, 456));
Settings.Add(new Setting<bool>("BoolSetting", true, false));
Settings.Add(new Setting<double>("FloatSetting", 3.14, 2.718));

// Iterate settings to do something (i.e. save all settings to a file)

foreach(var s in Settings)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Name of setting: " + s.Name);
   Console.WriteLine("Value of setting: " + s.Value.ToString());  // ERROR: no member named "Value"
}
```

(See fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/F4x2Di)

In attempting to iterate the settings, I can't access the Value or DefaultValue properties, since they're not present in the base class, and I can't attempt to cast the base class to a subclass, because I can't access the Value/DefaultValue properties to get their types to pass to the cast.

I also thought I could add a generic "object" property in the base class for Value and DefaultValue, then override it with the desired type in the subclass, but that's not allowed either: can't change type in overrides.

My remaining hair would greatly appreciate guidance on this one.  Is there a way to implement such a class with generic types in an iterable list? or is this the wrong approach to the problem at hand?

Comment: Just use `dynamic` for your playground code (`foreach(dynamic s in Settings)...` For real code use strongly typed settings like everyone else. There is really no way to make compiler to figure out what type will be there at run-time (notice that compile time happens *before* run-time)... so you either give up type safety (reflection or let `dynamic` do reflection correctly) or pick another approach.

Answer (score 2):

Well, thats a nice one.
If you would access it in the baseclass, the only type it could have is object (unless you restrict T)

So: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lHE1gv

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

abstract class BaseSetting
{
   protected abstract object GetValue();
    
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public object Value{ 
       get
       {
          return GetValue();
       }
   }
}

class Setting<T> : BaseSetting
{
   public Setting(string name, T value, T def) { Name = name; Value = value; DefaultValue = def; }
   public new T Value { get; set; }
   public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
   
   protected override object GetValue()
   {
      return Value;
   }
}





public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create iterable list of settings:
        List<BaseSetting> Settings = new List<BaseSetting>();
        Settings.Add(new Setting<int>("IntSetting", 123, 456));
        Settings.Add(new Setting<bool>("BoolSetting", true, false));
        Settings.Add(new Setting<double>("FloatSetting", 3.14, 2.718));

        // Iterate settings to do something (i.e. save all settings to a file)

        foreach(var s in Settings)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Name of setting: " + s.Name);
           Console.WriteLine("Value of setting: " + s.Value.ToString());  // ERROR: no member named "Value"
        }
            
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. I am testing it now. Can I also override the setter to accept values of the subclass's type?

Comment: No need to add ``Value`` to base class , I changed your code here https://dotnetfiddle.net/TwMFQB

Comment: @RyanGriggs your question is very nice one, and it can be solved as above, however, its probably still a problem when trying to get the things back out of the repo.

 for deserialization, you would have to also serialize the type of T, and make some voodoo magic, otherwise theres no chance to get it back out from the storage correctly typed.  i would go the factory way (and make it a different question hehe)

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer can you help me out with an example of "factory" way?

Answer (score 1):

Your `List` is of type `BaseSetting`. It does not contain those properties.

The iterated `Settings<T>` are extracted as `BaseSetting`.

To make use of the `Value` etc, you need to cast `s` to the appropriate type - for which you'll need to test for first, this can be done through `is`, but that is often an indication the solution is flawed:

```
if (s is Setting<int>)
   //Cast and do stuff with int
```

Because this is not very helpful, and you often know how to handle settings - they are well defined - setting implementations often just use strings or well defined JSON objects.

Alternatively, you can define a bunch of extension methods, or base your class on `object` but in both cases you will not gain more than just using a `string` as `Value`, and cast appropriate when you need it.

De facto this is also how it would work when desirialize into a class using JSON - but in that case you must know your setting names upfront.

Comment: Yes I know that - I'm asking how to fix it.  Can't add a generic override-able "object" to the base class because we're not allowed to override the type in subclasses.

Comment: Exactly: I can't cast 's' to the subclasses because I don't know what type the subclass uses.  I would have to look at the 'Value' and "DefaultValue' properties to determine what type they were.

Comment: How can I test the type without being able to access the property?

Comment: Use the `is` operator and cast. But I would advise against this path

Comment: using the IS operator in a class to find out which specialisation it is, or downcasting, is usually a indication that the design is flawed, i would strongly advise against that

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer: hence my remark: `But I would advise against this path` ;-)

Comment: I'll make it more explicit in the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Because you base class didn't have a Value property, We can try to use `abstract` property to let the subclass override it or use generics for `BaseSetting`

```
abstract class BaseSetting
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public abstract object Value { get; set; }
}

class Setting<T> : BaseSetting
{
   public Setting(string name, T value, T def) { Name = name; Value = value; DefaultValue = def; }
   public override object Value { get; set; }
   public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want to use `override` another way we can try to use [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier)  and set the value `base.Value` in the constructor function

```
abstract class BaseSetting
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public object Value { get; set; }
}

class Setting<T> : BaseSetting
{
   public Setting(string name, T value, T def) { 
       Name = name; 
       base.Value = value; 
       DefaultValue = def; 
   }
   public new T Value { 
        get{
           return (T)base.Value;
        } 
        set{
           base.Value = value; 
        }
   }
   public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jy2txh)

Comment: If you add the Value as an "object" to the base class, we can no longer use the Generics to set the type on the subclass (Setting<T>).  Instead we're stuck with a generic "object" for the subclass, which to me isn't ideal.

Comment: Hi  @RyanGriggs I edited my answer you can try that

Comment: @D-Shih thats a nice one and makes my answer obsolete